# Server-side processing Datatables pagination Microsoft SQL

Tags: php, jquery, sql, sql-server, datatables

Im trying to setup pagination with datatables using PHP PDO with MS SQL, since "limit" is not applicable i find it really hard to make the code work.

I have tried the "TOP" syntax but it will only filter the specified number and the pagination wont work.

I have tried offset and fetch still not working.

These is the working code when Mysql is used and its so easy to understand and perform.

```
if($_POST["length"] != -1)
   {
$query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
   }
```

These are the codes i tried (sorry im not really great in coding) :

```
//if($_POST["length"] != -1)
   {
Trial 1 : //$query .= "TOP " . $_POST['start'] . " OFFSET " .                     $_POST['length'];


Trial 2 : //$query .= "SELECT * from item ORDER BY id DESC offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only ";


    Trial 3 ://$query .="AND id BETWEEN ".intval( $_POST["start"] )." AND ".intval( $_POST["length"] );" "
```

}

The result should be a pagination with 10 filtered records each.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGxVw.png)

Update 1:

Here is the screenshot of the query i tried to test it in a MS SQL server but getting an error (using MS SQL 2008)

[SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKCVc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach depends on SQL Server version.

Approach, based on `ORDER BY` clause with `OFFSET` and `FETCH` as a [paging solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-offset-and-fetch-to-limit-the-rows-returned) requires SQL Server 2012+. Your syntax seems correct, so next code should work:

```
<?php
if ($_POST["length"] != -1) {
    $query = "
        SELECT * 
        FROM item 
        ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET ".($_POST['start']-1)." ROWS FETCH NEXT ".$_POST["length"]." ROWS ONLY
    ";
}
?>
```

For SQL Server 2008+, you may use `ROW_NUMBER()` as a paging solution:

```
<?php
if ($_POST["length"] != -1) {
    $query = 
        "SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS Rn
            FROM item
        )
        WHERE Rn BETWEEN ".$_POST['start']." AND ".($_POST['start'] + $_POST['length'] - 1);        
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for this. unfortunately still not working.  I use the codes you provided for SQL server 2008 since that is the version i am using. i'll post a screen shot for it to be clear.

Comment: hi!, its lacking the word "sub".  ---------------------------------------------------------- `sub WHERE Rn BETWEEN ". $_POST["start"] ." AND ". $_POST["start"] + $_POST["length"] - 1)` . its does not show any error but pagination still not working.

Comment: oh my god! its working perfectly now. i forgot to remove some brackets that i have added to test codes. i just added the word sub. its perfect. tank you so much!

Comment: adding the query to make the pagination works seems disabling the search functions. i cannot search now it just goes back to the first 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

In `MSSQL` to use the limit you will need to write your query like this:

```
ORDER BY X.Field
OFFSET 20 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROW ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

And this will skip the first 20 records and fetch the next 10.

Comment: hi! thank you. i tried this in MS SQL 2017 and its working but im currently working for 2008 version.